# Kafka manual commit behavior with consumer running constantly

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm learning Kafka and I'm playing with the following scenario, using JAVA API:

- manual commits
- single topic, single partition
- single producer, single consumer
- max.poll.records=5 or 1 (getting same result for both)

The producer puts some messages to Kafka. The consumer retrieves the messages and it is supposed to emulate an exception case behavior: randomly, once per ~10 messages, the offset it NOT commited. For the remaining 90%, the consumer calls a commitSynch after each message is processed.

The expected, good scenario:
If I emulate the exception case in the way that the consumer program finishes and consumer.close() is called, then everything goes as expected. That is, if offest 999 was the last uncommitted offset, then when I run the consumer program again, it will start from offset 999.

The unexpected scenario I need help with:
I want to do the same, but without exiting the consumer program. When the consumer processes a next message and randomly it decides not to acknowledge it, the flow simply goes to the next execution of consumer.poll. With that next poll, and again assuming that my last uncommitted offset was 999, I'd expect the message with offset 999 to be the first one returned. That's not the case though: I get consecutive messages with offsets 1000, 1001... so in effect the message with offset 999 is never re-processed, even though offset 999 has not been committed.

The thing that I'd like to understand first of all is this difference - the re-processing happens when the consumer program is run again, but it does not happen when the consumer is constantly running in a loop.

Comment: _if offest 999 was the last uncommitted offset, then when I run the consumer program again, it will start from offset 999._  - Typo? Did you mean committed here?

Comment: no, it is not a typo

Answer (score 0):

If the consumer is never restarted, then offsets will always be polled sequentially. That should be the expected behavior.

Only when it restarts will `auto.offset.reset` property take affect for uncommitted offsets, otherwise will use the committed value, which you're welcome to ignore by manually calling seek functions

That being said, if you're trying to implement reprocessing logic, your options are to temporarily track exception-causing offsets manually in memory and seek backwards+poll to retry, or to introduce a dead-letter topic for consuming later

Comment: seek is not what I'm after here: the goal is not to reprocess messages that have been already processed correctly. It is to re-attempt the reprocessing of a message that have not been processed because of an error.

Comment: Seek doesn't care about processed or not. It takes an arbitrary offset value. Re-subscribing does the exact same thing

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get my second scenario behaving as I wanted it to be (that is, exactly like the 1st scenario) by unsubscribing the consumer and subscribing again, when the exception condition occurs. When that's done, the consumer begins from the last uncommitted offset.

Comment: It should start immediately **after** the **committed** offset. There's no such thing as an "uncommitted" one.